# Performance of mapreduce with sorted keys

Tags: sorting, parallel-processing, mapreduce

In Google's paper it states:

> We guarantee that within a given partition, the intermediate
>   key/value pairs are processed in increasing key order. This ordering
>   guarantee makes it easy to generate a sorted output file per
>   partition, which is useful when the output file format needs to
>   support efficient random access lookups by key, or users of the output
>   find it convenient to have the data sorted.

I also tried with a simple example of "wordcount" with "mrJob" (Python) and it works as expected. In the output, all keys (words) are in alphabetical (ascending) order.

 However, I don't understand why it's possible. MapReduce is for parallel processing that means all sub-processes are independent. For example, a reducer calculates the frequency of a word and write to the output and then it finishes. But for an order output, apparently a sub-process has to wait others to compare the keys before write its output. This means it cannot leverage the power of parallel processing.

So how they solve it?

Thank you.

Comment: They did not. It is sorted per partition only.

Comment: oh, really? Maybe the result I got on my PC not general enough. I should test on cluster?

Comment: It is possible that your example was executed on only one partition. Try with a larger data set.